# Importing PHP My Admin database error

Tags: php, database, joomla, phpmyadmin

One of my customers asked me to update her Joomla website from 1.6 to 2.5

Becourse some files need editting for that to work i want to setup an test domain.

When i copied the PHPMyAdmin database file and imported it into my hosting pannel i get this error

```
SQL-query:



--
-- Databank: `information_schema`
--
CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL meldt: Documentatie
#1044 - Access denied for user 'jurjen'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Does anyone know why im getting this error and how i can fix this ?

The database file im using is "localhost.sql"

The domain im using for the test area is jurjenfolkertsma.nl/willy

Comment: Seems like your don't have the necessary permissions. Did you assign all possible permissions to the users for your database?

Comment: Im using this on a diffrend domain then where it comes from, could this give permission problems ?

Comment: No, the user you have assigned to your database doesn't have the correct permissions. Simply to to edit the user and assign all the necessary permissions

Comment: No, if you don't have the necessary permissions to import or create a table you can't really proceed.

Comment: I can make new databases for myself so i think this is kinda strange ?

Comment: Try making a new database, creating a new user, assign that user to the created database, assign ALL permissions to the user, import your .sql file

Comment: Why would you add an `information_schema`, that's mysql's job ;)

Comment: Im just importing the database backup and phpmyadmin is shouting information_schema at me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you took a dump of *all* the databases on your customer's server. Probably what you want is to dump only the Joomla database and export the associated users. You can't create `information_schema` because it already exists and besides, it's not a standard database. It's internal to MySQL and you probably don't really want to modify it anyway.

You should do the dump again or edit your .sql file to only get the Joomla database. Then from the Users tab, you can click the `Export` button for whatever Joomla users exist (there might be one, there might be more than one; I'm not certain). That way, you can also import the proper user permissions. Create the user on your system, give them the same password, then import the permissions.

[image: User export page]

Answer (score 0):

User jurjen'@'localhost don't have the access to information_schema. Add user to database in your admin panel or software like sqlYog but to be able to do that you need root privileges.
Also I don't think you need to change information_schema table just transfer the joomla tables to your host

Answer (score -2):

SQL-query:

```
--
-- Databank: `information_schema`
--
CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL meldt: Documentatie
#1044 - Access denied for user 'jurjen'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Hello
I gone through your importing Database error. when you are importing Database just change database name using Notepad++ ..

Comment: Nope - his user doesent have the access to database so it won't work

Comment: so if i name the backupfile diffrend (example:test.sql) i just could make it into a new database and change the config file from joomla for it to work ?